# Hide an attribute with ng-hide

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, pug

I'm using an input field value attribute to show the query that the has user entered on the SERP of my app. I want to hide the value that was queried on pages where the result is undefined. Is it possible to use ng-show to just hide an attribute and not the entire element?

#### Jade

```
    div(ng-controller="SearchCtrl", class="header-search-form")
      form(id="search-form-homepage" class="input-group input-lg")
        input(type="search",
        ng-enter="doSearch(query.term)",
        ng-hide="query.term === 'undefined'",
        ng-model="query.term",
        class="form-control header-search-result",
        value="#{data.query}")
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are saying but I don't think so.  What would this look like in HTML?  I don't get what you even mean by 'hide an attribute'.  Angular just creates HTML so if it isn't something you can do with HTML then no.  It sounds like you have a `query.term` value that is loaded with the page and you don't want to show it if it is undefined, but you still want the user to be able to type something?  When you set the value you should probably just clear it.

Comment: Ok cool, I understand the confusion of trying to remove the value of the attribute. In HTML this removes the input element completely.

Comment: Must be something about Jade, I don't see anything about a placeholder...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to create your own directive for this task.  As an [example - plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FQJ78mFlaXUlXBVp54cJ?p=preview), I have created a directive that will remove the placeholder attribute.

Note the key difference here is that we can't "hide" attributes since hide is really

```
display: 0;
```

we can just remove or add them.

```
app.directive('attrHide', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      attrHide: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attr){
      var targetAttr = attr.hiddenAttribute;
      var saveAttr = attr[targetAttr] || '';

      scope.$watch('attrHide', function(newVal){
        if (newVal){
          elm.removeAttr(targetAttr);
        } else {
          elm.attr(targetAttr,saveAttr);
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

In the markup you can have

```
<input  ng-model="target"/>
<input placeholder="hello" hidden-attribute="placeholder" attr-hide="target=='hello'"/>
```

Here in the attr-hide, you can put the true false expression and in hidden-attribute you can choose the attribute to remove